# How to insert a table inside a frame?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a frame with buttons and plotting options and wanted to include a table as well in that frame. Is there any example or suggestion on how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The wxpython demo is full of examples of all differant controls.

Comment: I have seen many examples of using tables but not a table along with buttons, text controls, and static text. Can you please point to any such example?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a wx.grid.Grid in most cases. You could use a wx.ListCtrl or an ObjectListView widget too. The idea is to put the widgets inside of sizers. So you could have a top level BoxSizer in vertical orientation that contains another sizer or sizers. In this case, I would create a sizer to hold the buttons and nest that sizer in the top level sizer. Then add the table (i.e. grid) to the top level sizer and you're done.